# Set <a href> width as Link length without specifying specific length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/xkryh20s/

```css
a{
 display:block;
}
a:hover{
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<a href="something">Link 1</a>
<a href="something">Link 2</a>
<a href="something">Link 3</a>
<a href="something">Link 4</a>
```

As you can see, the link is taking the whole width but I want it to only take up the actual word's length without stating "width:100px" or some other number.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to only take up the actual word's length without stating "width:100px" or some other number

If so, It'd better to keep the link inline.

```css
a:hover{
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="something">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="something">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="something">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="something">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might just need to make it `display:inline-block;` - Probably wouldn't hurt to make it an unordered list too; i've just added a bit of extra css to fix the formatting.

```css
a{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px;
}
a:hover{
  background:black;
  color:white;
}

ul {
  padding-left:0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="something">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="something">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="something">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="something">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Paulie_D - `clear:left;` is now removed - left it in there accidentally.

Comment: You should also be aware that although the links are now shrink-wrapped...the `li` are not. They're still 100% wide.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - have edited the snippet to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

With the minimum changing of your code I would say `display:table;`

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xkryh20s/10/)

```
a{
 display: table;

}
a:hover{
  background:black;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the optimal solution for the layout required without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

By default, blocks have a `fill-available` width. It seems you want `fit-content` instead.

You can

- Use `width: fit-content`. Not widely supported, some browser may need vendor prefixes.

  ```css
  a {
    display: block;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <a href="something">Link 1</a>
  <a href="something">Link 2</a>
  <a href="something">Link 3</a>
  <a href="something">Link 4</a>
  ```
- Use `display: inline-block`. Their width is `fit-content` by default, but be aware they are inline-level. You may need to insert additional elements to force line breaks.

  ```css
  ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li><a href="something">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="something">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="something">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="something">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```
- Use `float: left; clear: left`. Floated elements have `fit-content` width by default. You need clearing to prevent them from stacking horizontally. Be aware they will become out-of-flow, so consider using clearfix or establishing a block formatting content on the parent.

  ```css
  div {
    overflow: hidden; /* Establish block formatting context */
  }
  a {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <a href="something">Link 1</a>
    <a href="something">Link 2</a>
    <a href="something">Link 3</a>
    <a href="something">Link 4</a>
  </div>
  ```
- `display: table`. This is kinda hacky, but it's block-level and the width algorithm is usually like `fit-content` (be aware it's implementation-dependent).

  ```css
  a {
    display: table;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <a href="something">Link 1</a>
  <a href="something">Link 2</a>
  <a href="something">Link 3</a>
  <a href="something">Link 4</a>
  ```
- Place the `a` inside a wrapper with `fit-content` width

  ```css
  div {
    display: inline-block; /* fit-content width */
  }
  a {
    display: block;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: black;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div>
    <a href="something">Link 1</a>
    <a href="something">Link 2</a>
    <a href="something">Link 3</a>
    <a href="something">Link 4</a>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `display:block;` property that's doing this - block elements (like `<div>`s) will automatically consume 100% of their parent's width. You could wrap the links in a styled un-ordered list to produce the desired affect:

CSS:

```
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
a:hover{
  background:black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="something">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="something">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="something">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="something">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2L4tk43/

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

https://jsfiddle.net/xkryh20s/11/

```
a{
 display:block;

}
a:hover{
  background:black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid to use pseudo-elements, you can do:

```
a:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

See answer [In CSS, what is a better way of forcing a line break after an element than making it a block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759132/in-css-what-is-a-better-way-of-forcing-a-line-break-after-an-element-than-makin)

Answer (score 0):

Links are `inline` by default so just removing the `display:block` will shrink them to their own width.

How you arrange them after that is another question.

```css
a {
  background: red;
}
a:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="something">Link 1</a>
<a href="something">Link 2</a>
<a href="something">Link 3</a>
<a href="something">Link 4</a>
```